# Error Codes Media Player syntax and definition

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, error-code

I cannot find any documentation on error codes with regard to Android. I am putting together an app that seemed to be working on a lower level API setup but not on a higher one.
The error occurs when trying to play an audio file and like I said it all worked in a lower version.

The error code I see is in the log are:

> MediaPlayer info/warning (1, 32)
>   MediaPlayer Info (1,32)
>   MediaPlayer info/warning (1,26)
>   MediaPlayer Info (1,26)
>   MediaPlayer error(351, -4)
>   MediaPlayer Error(351,-4)
>   VideoView Error(351,-4)

So can someone please explain how this works in detail?
I know I have an error in `MediaPlayer` and possibly `VideoView` as per the data above but what do the numbers represent? I assume it is a particular error but which one?

I can not seem to find anything on this and how this is decoded. 
Where can I find documentation on how to find out what this means that is the main question.

If I can get an answer for this particular error code even better, but again the actual documentation source so I may be able to look up additional codes myself would be of great benefit also.

Here is the exact logfile as exported by Eclipse:

```
07-04 12:22:48.298: V/key =(6969): http://xxxxxx/glennharrold/audio/normal/relaxsleepwellfull.mp3
07-04 12:22:48.388: D/MediaPlayer(6969): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side   
07-04 12:22:48.388: D/SprintMM(6969): Proxy will be bypassed because of WIFI connection.
07-04 12:22:48.508: W/MediaPlayer(6969): info/warning (1, 32)
07-04 12:22:48.508: I/MediaPlayer(6969): Info (1,32)
07-04 12:22:48.508: W/MediaPlayer(6969): info/warning (1, 26)
07-04 12:22:48.508: I/MediaPlayer(6969): Info (1,26)
07-04 12:22:48.508: E/MediaPlayer(6969): error (351, -4)
07-04 12:22:48.508: E/MediaPlayer(6969): Error (351,-4)
07-04 12:22:48.508: D/VideoView(6969): Error: 351,-4
```

Now what is unclear is exactly what means what I can see that it may have something to do with the file not being found on the client side but this exact same code works on a lower API version I copied working code to this App to make a new one. 
The only thing I see in this that I did not see in my logcat in Eclipse is the `(6969)` and the `D/`, `E/`, `W/`, `I/` in front of MediaPlayer text
don't know what this extra stuff means and it only appears when I export the code to a text file.

Comment: Source code, logcat, what have you researched on? What were your conclusions? What testing have you done? What did you try?

Comment: The above is from the logcat. Did online searches for pretty much anything to do with mediaPlayer error codes with out success. I have looked at the data being input to the media player and it all looks good BUT more importantly where can I find error code defintions so I can at least get pointed in the right direction and add the definitions to my debugging resources

Comment: Your logcat is trimmed down for some reason and too vague, thus have no idea what that is about nor is it helpful either. Suggest you re-edit your question to include the **full** logcat detailing the errors. :)

Comment: edited as suggested. The media link does exist and is accessible in other Apps. this is actually a new App that is going to be an update to an older version of the App that is how I know the link works

Comment: How does the MP3 sound? does it play ok on a computer? What bit-rate is it at? Might be worth it to check if it does actually play properly on android's own stock media player for a start, if that does not play, you have your answer :)

Comment: Error box pops up and says video cannot be played But as I said the exact same audio link/media file plays in another similar App using the same code

Comment: no, am not talking about your code, am talking about the stock application to play the media, this is for your checking to make sure its confirmed that the media is not corrupted.

Comment: Where can I find out what the 351 and -4 mean why is this not easily identified I can not get a straight answer on this at all I saw something that mentions  pvm?? or something close to it and it has the specific error codes listed and their meaning but nothing about this. Is this hidden on purpose????

Comment: when I open the link in a web browser it plays absolutely fine.

Comment: Have you tried the stock media player, not the web browser? Because the web browser has its own plugin to handle it... that's what am trying to eliminate..

Comment: I am placing a bet that the media is incompatible and not handled by the stock Android's OS own version of media player. Otherwise why is it reporting errors/warnings as a result of playing it...

Comment: Have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, When logcat displays information it is one of the following:

- D - **D** ebug
- W - **W** arning
- I - **I** nformation

Followed by a '/' with a identifier to identify the Java code name which is usually defined by TAG as in a standard practice of doing :

```
public class fooClass{
    private static final String TAG = "fooClass";
    // ... SNIP
}
```

Following that, is the process id of the Java code that is running in the DalvikVM, along with some informative error code/message depending on the program spec.

For example, continuing on from the Java class `fooClass` as highlighted above, suppose it has a function `fooMethod` like this:

```
private void fooMethod(){    
    Log.d(TAG, "fooMethod() - This is a debug message");    
    //    
    Log.i(TAG, "fooMethod() - This is a info message");    
    //    
    Log.w(TAG, "fooMethod() - This is a warning message"); 
}
```

Now that will show up in the log like this:

```
07-04 20:58:00 D/fooClass (1234): fooMethod() - This is a debug message 
07-04 20:58:00 I/fooClass (1234): fooMethod() - This is a info message 
07-04 20:58:00 W/fooClass (1234): fooMethod() - This is a warning message
```

Some apps, will elect to display the message at the programmer's discretion or display a cryptic message.

Notably within the Android framework itself, some services will display a meaningless message that has little significance to anyone except the developer(s) behind the ROM itself, to aid in troubleshooting.

***Edit:*** Since the OP insisted on trying to nail down understanding this, here goes

The AOSP source code for the MediaPlayer lies on github [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java), look in there there's a reference to 'pvmf_return_codes.h' in the source on line number **1547**, which, a quick google-fu lead to this [linky](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/external/opencore/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h). The error code and condition is as a result of incompatible or media error.

Comment: Thank you this is the basic information I was looking for so as I understand this now the first number (351) doesn't really mean anything and the -4 means this according to the 2nd document you mentioned  
    const PVMFStatus PVMFErrNotSupported = (-4);
    /*
     Error due to invalid argument   
    */

Comment: Don't forget that... `const PVMFStatus PVMFInfoSourceFormatNotSupported = 32;` was mentioned in the above in the 'Warning' part :) `const PVMFStatus PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart = 26;` is for the exception handling if you'd like to put it that way, it starts with 26, then encounters 32, so based on the order of the sequence, it could be the MediaPlayer service could not handle it, either the mp3 is in the wrong codec format or something... difficult to say or pin down exactly what is it!

Comment: Thank you so very much that does help immensely I would have responded sooner but was sick so by backtracking on that first link you gave me I can find the detailed information on a given error type ignore the middle numbers and focus on the last one which is actually the important part

Comment: Glad I could help, hope you're recovering okie :)

Comment: Can you upvote and mark this answer solved if it has satisfied you? :)

Comment: Reputation is not high enough to upvote it I checked it though